# Custom Rectangle Class Not Working

Tags: java, class, graphics, jpanel, extends

I created a class that extends Rectangle(TransformRect). I want it to spawn itself randomly on the JPanel, then move around randomly. So far my class spawns itself,but doesn't move around randomly. When I draw my TransformRect object in my TranformPanel, it seems to run all the code before actually spawning.It runs throught the sleep loops(try,catch), and then actually spawns itself using the random coords and 1 use of the movement method. I have no idea how to fix this.

TransformRect

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class TransformRect extends Rectangle{ 
    //instance initializer
    {   
        Random rn = new Random(); 
        this.setBounds(rn.nextInt(450),rn.nextInt(450), 10, 10);   
        System.out.println(this.getBounds());

    }    
    public TransformRect(){ 
        try {  
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            this.translate(10, 10); 
            System.out.println(this.getBounds());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

TranformPanel

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TranformPanel extends JPanel {
    private double randomx = 0; 
    private double randomy = 0; 
    private int xlist[] = new int[20]; 
    private int ylist[] = new int[20]; 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        drawTransform(g,randomx,randomy);
    }  
    private void drawTransform(Graphics g,double randomx,double randomy) 
    {    
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;    
        g2d.draw(new TransformRect()); 
    }
}
```

EDIT- Camickr: I know it only paints one TransformRect. The problem is that the translate method(this.translate(10, 10)) doesn't work. The TransformRect isn't moving itself around the page and I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TransformPanel only every paints one TransformRect.

If you want to paint multiple rectangles then you need to keep a List of all the rectangles and iterate through the List do paint each rectangle.

Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It has an `addRectangle(...)` method that allows you to add a rectangle to paint.

Also, whenever you translate the rectangles location you need to invoke `repaint()` on the TransformPanel to tell it to repaint itself.

Comment: I know it only paints one TransformRect. The problem is that the translate method(this.translate(10, 10)) doesn't work. The TransformRect isn't moving itself around the page and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The whole structure of your code is wrong. I already mentioned that you need to invoke repaint() on the panel to paint an object in a new location. However, when you do that you paint a new instance of the RectangleRect so it will be painted at its original position.

Comment: I looked at the addRectangle() method and the rest of DrawOnComponent, but I still don't know how to fix it. I understand what you mean when you said that the RectangleRect gets repainted when repaint() is invoked. I just don't know how to fix it so it translates the rectangle without creating a new instance when repainting.

Comment: @Ninjaman494, the basic structure of your code needs to be changed. The Timer should be part of the panel, not the Rectangle. When the Timer fires you invoke the translate(...) method on all the Rectangle is the ArrayList, so all the Rectangles (1 or more in my example) change at the same time. Then you invoke repaint() so all the Rectangles get painted at one time. So as last line says in the blog: have fun and try adding animation to the example.